# How do I run Clam TK antivirus in 16.10?

Tags: updates, clamtk

The good help I get here is much appreciated always. I'm not too up to date on computers and can't seem to get clam to run. I have ubuntu 16.10 (I'm not in a good situation right now to update to 17.04). I bring up ClamTK and try everything but I can't get it to scan my whole laptop like I used to. It said it ran a scheduled scan but it seemed to take about 2 minutes which doesn't seem long enough. Also it says there is an update. I run the general update manager on my system regularly but it still says there is an update. How do I scan my whole computer, and update? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Start ClamTk. Push the `Scan a directory` button.

[image]

Click once on `File System`, then click OK

[image]

To update the ClamTk user interface, click on the gold star in the main ClamTk window, which brings up the `About` information. Click on `Homepage` and that will take you to the user interface's software page. Find the `deb` installer for Ubuntu. Download it. Install it.

[image]